# If statement better understanding

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I was working on some backend node.js if condition when i realized i wasnt getting an error when i do this `if (value.accepters !== undefined && value.accepters.length !== 0)` while checking an object with a missing key but if i do `value.accepters.length` i get error, can anyone explain why for better understanding, thanks.

An example:
a bit messy, please don't mind.
[image]

**Code Update**

```
var value = {accepters: ["id1"], rejecters: [], blockedRoom: []}
// did some long code work here
value = {accepters: ["id1"], rejecters: []}
console.log("blockedRoom check 1:", value.blockedRoom !== undefined && value.blockedRoom.length !== 0) // No Error
console.log("blockedRoom check 2:", value.blockedRoom.length !== 0) // Error

var accepters = 0;
var rejecters = 0;
var amongAccepters = false;
var amongRejecters = false;
var amongBlockers = false;
// No Error
if (value.accepters !== undefined && value.accepters.length !== 0){
  accepters = value.accepters.length;
  const foundUserAmongAccepters = value.accepters.find(
    (v) => v.key === key
  );
  if (foundUserAmongAccepters !== undefined) {
    amongAccepters = true;
  }
}
if (value.rejecters !== undefined && value.rejecters.length !== 0) {
  rejecters = value.rejecters.length;
  const foundUserAmongRejecters = value.rejecters.find(
    (v) => v.key === key
  );
  if (foundUserAmongRejecters !== undefined) {
    amongRejecters = true;
  }
}
if (value.blockedRoom !== undefined && value.blockedRoom.length !== 0) {
  const foundUserAmongBlockers = value.blockedRoom.find((v) => v === key);
  if (foundUserAmongBlockers !== undefined) {
    amongBlockers = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Since you don't get "hmm" or "hmmmmm" I'd assume that l.m is undefined.

Comment: `&&` performs short-circuiting. So when you write `expression1 && expression2`, `expression2` is not evaluated when `expression1` is false. So you don't get an error in the second expression if the first one prevents it.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? If you try to read a property of `undefined` you get an error. Only trying to read the property of the value after you have confirmed if it is not `undefined` avoids that problem.

Comment: something *being* undefined doesn't cause an error. accessing a property on something that doesn't exist *does* cause an error.

Comment: @Barmar i added code but i think i get it now, in an if statement the first check while doing `if (value.blockedRoom!== undefined && value.blockedRoom.length !== 0)` failed because `blockedRoom` is not in the object and that means it won't check if it has any length even though it has `&&` operator, correct me if i am wrong, thanks.

Comment: @Barmar just saw ur explanation, clear things up will consider this solved, thanks.

Comment: That's correct. You can also use the ES6 optional chaining operator syntax: `value?.blockedRoom?.length !== 0`

Comment: @Barmar nicee, will test and make use of this `value?.blockedRoom?.length !== 0` thanks.

Comment: @Barmar can help write up the solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You set `var l = { k: 1 }`

And then you try to log `m.length`, that doesn't exist.

You then check if `l.m` is **not** `undefined`, and log. It's undefined, so you don't log.

You then do the same check, is `l.m`? It's not, so we should circuit the `if` check and we don't log.

Next, try to log `l.m.length`, we know `l.m` is undefined, so `l.m.length` is undefined. Error

Next you try to do an `if` check on something we already know fails, because `l.m` is undefined, `l.m.length` fails (`undefined.length` == error), so the `=== 0`  never happens.

Same as last comment.

Finally, check if `l.m` is defined, it's not, short circuit to `false`.

Comment: Thanks i think i understand now, `Finally, check if l.m is defined, it's not, short circuit to false` i was wondering why it's not checking for the length after it knows that `m` is not in the object, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solution and better understandings from [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

> && performs short-circuiting. So when you write expression1 && expression2, expression2 is not evaluated when expression1 is false. So you don't get an error in the second expression if the first one prevents it.

Comment: Or you could simply ask @Barmar to write up an answer if this does actually solve your problem, so that we maintain the correct incentives.

Comment: @jarmod ah sure noted.

Comment: @Barmar can help write up the solution?  thanks.